# tmux split panes not rendering properly in Conemu

Tags: cygwin, tmux, conemu

I'm trying to use tmux over ssh (cygwin) in conemu, and keep running into the following issue.

I'll start with a vertically split screen that seems to be fine:

[image: seemingly functional split screen]

And switch to the right split, hit enter a couple of times, and things will start disappearing.
[image: broken split screen]

There's something wrong with how tmux is handled with Conemu; this works fine if I have split screens in vim outside of tmux, but breaks again with vim split screens in tmux (even when the split is a vim split, not a tmux split). This is handled properly in Cygwin.

This happens regardless of the shell. I have tried commenting out my ~/.tmux.conf, and the issue persists.

Comment: This is cygwin's bug and it must be reported to cygwin's authors. More details in wiki: http://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/CygwinMsys

Comment: So this is the same bug which prevents Conemu from processing 256 color escape codes over ssh? Or is this different? 

At any rate, is there anything we can all do to get this working? I understand that this is not something either you or they can solve individually, but Conemu seems to be the closest to a proper terminal Windows has, and Cygwin is the closest thing to a proper shell - it'd be nice to have them working together.

Comment: cygwin/mingw do not put ANSI codes into ConEmu-handled console. Their logic and arguments are simple: Windows console does not support ANSI codes. And they do not want to know anything about other terminal emulators. Yeah, there is `cygwin terminal emulation subsystem` (which is used by mintty and some others). But they are not a "true" Windows consoles... What can you do? I don't know. May be in future I will mix both worlds in the ConEmu, but that is not my priority.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies. Here's to hoping that there's a solution one day. In the meantime, is there a public discussion of this topic with Cygwin? I can't seem to find it easily.

Comment: For example: https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2014-05/msg00028.html

Comment: Meh... I like ConEmu for its tweaks-see-I-could-like-Quake, I like Cygwin for its Linux-on-Windows feature and I was about to like tmux for its attach-to-session, but apparently I couldn't make them work together. Tough world.